# Using Python to reformat a tab delimited text file to a format usable by another program

Tags: python-2.7

I've got a program that creates an output of a XYZ file however for some reason the files outputted are YXZ, I need the x and y columns to be switched.  Additionally the x and y values have hemisphere marking at the end.  Example:

```
00.000000W  000.000000S 0.000
```

I need to remove these hemisphere markings and multiple the values by -1 to make them a true decimal degree format so I can read them into my next program.  Any value with a "S" or "W" at the end will need to be multiplied by -1, any value with "N" or "E" at the end can simply be removed.  If this can be done it will save me countless hours.  I can perform this operation with excel but sometimes my files are to large for excel to work with.  Please any help I can get would be great.

This is what I've got so far and it works to switch the X and Y value around, however I'm stuck on removing and multiplying by -1 for any value ending with "S" or "W".

```
infile="my.txt"
outfile="my_edited.txt"

read_infile=open(infile,'r')
write_outfile=open(outfile,'w')

reader=csv.reader(read_infile, delimiter='\t')
writer=csv.writer(writting, delimiter='\t')

for row in reader:
    writer.writerow([row[1], row[0], row[2]])
```

Comment: quick hack that works, but is bad and not pythonic:
`for row in reader:
    new_row = []
    new_row.append(float(row[1][:-1] * [-1,1][row[1][-1] in "NE"])
    new_row.append(float(row[0][:-1] * [-1,1][row[0][-1] in "NE"])
    new_row.append(float(row[2]))
    writer.writerow(new_row)
`
Hopefully someone will write you a more reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer keeps everything as a string, and assumes that appending `"-1"` to the beginning of a string is enough to make it negative. Note that `''.join(["Hello, ", "World!"])` is actually the Pythonic way to concatenate strings, and that `-1` retrieves the last character in a string: `[1,2,3][-1] == 3`.

```
infile="my.txt"
outfile="my_edited.txt"

read_infile=open(infile,'r')
write_outfile=open(outfile,'w')

reader=csv.reader(read_infile, delimiter='\t')
writer=csv.writer(write_outfile, delimiter='\t')

for row in reader:
    lng = row[0][:-1]
    lat = row[1][:-1]

    if row[0][-1] == 'W':
        lng = ''.join(["-1", lng])

    if row[1][-1] == 'S':
        lat = ''.join(["-1", lat])

    writer.writerow([lat, lng, row[2]])
```